# find the exact list of words in list of strings in python?

Tags: python, string, python-re

I have two list of strings:

```
grids = ['north', 'eaSt', 'West','noRtheast', 'soUth']
links = ['north-northeast', 'north-south']
```

I want to check that what `grids` are there in the `links`. So I wrote a program for this:

```
import re

grids = ['north', 'eaSt', 'West','noRtheast', 'soUth']
links = ['north-northeast', 'north-south']

for search in grids:
    for text in links:
        result = re.findall('\\b' + search + '\\b', text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
        print(result)
```

OUTPUT:

```
['north']
['north']
[]
[]
[]
[]
['northeast']
[]
[]
['south']
```

I almost got the output but don't understand that why am I getting those blanks in the output, so can I get the simpler and clean alternative for this one, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably don't need regex for this.  Just check if the string exists.

```
grids = ['north', 'eaSt', 'West','noRtheast', 'soUth']
links = ['north-northeast', 'north-south']
for l in links:
    print(f'{l} contains {[x for x in grids if x.lower() in l.lower().split("-")]}')
```

Output

```
north-northeast contains ['north', 'noRtheast']
north-south contains ['north', 'soUth']
```

Comment: Hey thanks, man that's a very clean approach.

Answer (score 2):

Your code printing resoult also when regural Exp don't find enything.
You can just add some `if` checking whether the array is empty

```
import re

grids = ['north', 'eaSt', 'West','noRtheast', 'soUth']
links = ['north-northeast', 'north-south']

for search in grids:
    for text in links:
        result = re.findall('\\b' + search + '\\b', text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
        if len(result):
            print(result)
```

Comment: Yes, that can be the logic of this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the library "re" but i think i can solve your problem like this :

```
grids = ['north', 'eaSt', 'West','noRtheast', 'soUth']
links = ['north-northeast', 'north-south']

for search in grids:
    for text in links:
        if search.lower() in text.lower():
            print('find '+search+' in '+text+' !')
```

The method .lower() on string will lowercase all case-based characters, and the operator `in` will return true if the string `search` is in the string `text`.

Comment: well, the only problem with this method is that it will also print 'east'  from the 'links', which is not there actually. I have tried this method.

Answer (score 1):

okay i have misunderstanding, you can split the chain before compare :

```
grids = ['north', 'eaSt', 'West','noRtheast', 'soUth']
links = ['north-northeast', 'north-south']

for search in grids:
    for text in links:
        for text_split in text.split('-'):
            if search.lower() == text_split.lower():
                print('find '+search+' in '+text+' !')
```

OUTPUT:

```
find north in north-northeast !
find north in north-south !
find noRtheast in north-northeast !
find soUth in north-south !
```